# ¿Cómo customizar/estilizar los campos predeterminados del formulario de reinicio de contraseña en Django?

Tags: django, web, django-forms, framework, desarrollo

Me encuentro en un proceso de auto aprendizaje de Django y es una herramienta que me ha gustado bastante de lo poco que llevo estudiado. He logrado integrar vistas, direcciones url, modelos con sus respectivas bases de datos, extender plantillas html, etc. En lo concerniente al tema de inicio y cierre de sesión, registro no he tenido mayor problema y he podido incluso personalizar con un poco de css los campos que por defecto trae Django para el login y registro, incluso pude agregar campos adicionales al proceso de registro de un usuario. Sin embargo, el problema que no he podido resolver en mi proceso de de aprendizaje es que no he podido personalizar los campos que vienen por defecto para el reinicio de la contraseña (adjunto algunas imágenes).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como han podido observar en las imágenes que les he compartido, la última imagen es cuando el usuario solicita el reinicio de su contraseña tras solicitarla vía correo electrónico. El punto es que en este momento estoy en un dilema pues acorde a la documentación de Django existen dos formas de solicitar un reinicio de contraseña usando los formularios predeterminados que son [setpasswordform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) y passwordchangeform, éste último te pide que sepas tu contraseña para poder cambiar tu contraseña, así que el que usé para empezar este ejercicio fue el formulario setpasswordform.

Sin embargo, no sé como usar este formulario en el archivo forms.py ya que hay poca o nula información sobre como podría manipular directamente este formulario por defecto de Django cuando menos crear uno nuevo personalizado para agregar aquí mis estilos. Déjenme darles un ejemplo de lo que hice con el formulario PasswordResetForm en el archivo forms.py:

class NewPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
def **init**(self, *args, **kargs):
super(NewPasswordResetForm, self).**init**(*args, **kargs)

```
email = forms.EmailField(label="Reinicio de Correo Electrónico:", 
    max_length=150, required=True, 
    widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs=({"class":"form-control", "id":"email-reset","placeholder":"si perdiste o no recuerdas tu contraseña, empieza aquí el proceso de recuperacion"}
            )))
```

Donde el campo email, quiero entender, lo abstrae (quizás desde AbstractUser todavia no me queda del todo claro) y por esa razón puedo invocar el mismo nombre de variable de email para verificar que esta ya dado de alta y puedo entonces mandar el correo. El punto es que no estoy del todo seguro si debo hacer algo similar en setpasswordform y poder manipular variables como password1 y password.

De antemano agradezco el apoyo, comentarios, sugerencias, criticas a esta encrucijada en la que me encuentro.

Saludos a la comunidad.
CC